# Can I opt out of single-handedly closing questions via the gold badge privilege?

Tags: discussion, privileges, tag-badges

Sometimes, I run into questions where I *think* it's a duplicate, but I'm not sure. In those cases, I'd like to suggest the duplicate, but I don't want to close the new question all by myself. I've done that on occasion before, but now that I have the gold [java] tag badge, I can't any more.

Can I opt out of that privilege, either completely or on a per-question basis?

Comment: Just post a comment saying something like "Does this solve your problem: [link]". There is currently no way to opt out.

Comment: You're a super expert whether you want it or not buddy. At least when it comes to delete privileges and such you can donate reputation points through bounties to drop below the threshold again, but shedding gold badges is impossible. Yeah IMO the Mjolnir hammer should be a configurable option. But all we can do is cast some pointless upvotes on the feature request, you're going to have to live with it. IMO this is a valid reason to have a sock puppet.

Comment: @Gimby I appreciate the support but I don't think a sock puppet is the solution.

Comment: Correct, it'd be a workaround.

Comment: Here is the thing about duplicates, if the community doesn’t agree, the question can be reopened and in the process the question probably is improved resulting in a better quality question